# C++ class declaration in objective-c header

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I want to declare a class c++ style in a objective-c header, but i get an error "error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__ attribute __' before 'CPPClass'"

Here is code from the .h file.

```
class CPPClass;  
@interface OBJCClass : NSObject  
{  
    CPPClass* m_pCPPObject;  
}  
@end
```

if i implement it objective-c style `@class CPPClass` i get an error when defining it, saying that it can't find the interface declaration. Is there anyway of doing this, otherwise, all the objective-c classes that import my header file with the imported c++ header must also be .mm files.

ps. i've have renamed the m file to mm.

Comment: What are the files you have? CPPClass.cpp, CPPClass.h, OBJCClass.mm and OBJCClass.h ?
What is the file-being-compiled actually listed immediately prior to the compile error.
My guess is that the .cpp file is actually complaining when it #includes the file with the obj-c definitions.

Comment: the classes are as you said, the cpp file never includes the OBJCClass.h . I think the problem is that other obj-c classes includes OBJCClass.h and can't interpret the c style declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the cpp class only when compiling C++. Use a typedef to void otherwise:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
class CPPClass;
#else
typedef void CPPClass;
#endif
```

This way, non C++ compilation units see the instance variable as a void pointer. Since all pointers are of the same size, the type of the instance variable does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Rename any files that include it as having .mm extensions. This will tell the compiler to compile with the `-ObjC++` flag.

Comment: I was afraid of that, it is more than a couple of files that includes that file and was hoping that there was some way of going around that :(